# SELECT GUID using sql.js returns no result

Tags: sql, sqlite, guid, sql.js

I am trying to return a specific row of my sqlite table by using its GUID.

The table "Reference" is defined as

```
CREATE TABLE "Reference" ( `ID` GUID, [...], PRIMARY KEY(`ID`) )
```

When returning all rows via `SELECT ID FROM Reference` I get the GUID values as comma-separated decimals (plus one number (probably zero) is missing, the one before the last block), e.g. one of my result GUIDs is `20,129,73,9,133,47,79,7,80,130,247,254,95,40,35,29`.

Now, if I try to select the whole row using this GUID, I don't get any result.

Example query:

```
SELECT * FROM Reference WHERE ID = '20,129,73,9,133,47,79,7,80,130,247,254,95,40,35,29'
```

Further, I already tried converting the decimals to hex or ascii values and used them instead - without success though.

Comment: What does `SELECT TYPEOF(ID) FROM Reference` give you?

Comment: It returns ``blob``.

Comment: Your response inspired me to play around with other ways of getting back the cell values. So I tried ``SELECT hex(ID) from Reference`` which returns the respective hex values. Further, I can select individual rows with ``SELECT * FROM Reference WHERE hex(ID) = '14814909852F4F075082F7FE5F28231D'``. However, I'd still be interested in a "non-hex" way to retrieve the rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the GUIDs are stored as 16-byte blobs, and that JavaScript code is converting them to an array of integers representing the bytes.  But the syntax that SQLite uses for blob literals is an X-prefixed hex string, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Reference WHERE ID = X'14814909852F4F075082F7FE5F28231D'
```

Comment: I have tried before to select a row using the x-prefixed string and got ``Error: unrecognized token: [...]``. Looks like I used a malformed GUID/hex value. Thanks for pointing that out!